# How do I get ReadXml to build a DataSet using the entire XML structure, rather than just the first node?

Tags: xml, vb.net, reporting-services, dataset, ssrs-2008

How do I get ReadXml to build a DataSet using the entire XML structure, rather than just the first node?

I'm using DataSet.ReadXml(MemoryStream) to read in the results of an SSRS XML steam.

Export SSRS to XML error "A column named 'Value' already belongs to the DataTable: cannot set a nested table name of the same name.

I get the error becuase some child nodes have blank atributes, and others don't  Basically, the first Parent has children with all blank child attributes, and the second Parent has some children that do have values for thier attributes. When ReadXml builds the dataset it uses the structure of the first Parent, then bombs when reading in the second parent.

I am calling the same SSRS report with different date ranges. With short date ranges, when there is less data and I get the error. With longer date ranges the problem doesn't exist. The structure of the XML doesn't change, except a node such as:

```
<TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Sep&#xA;&#xD;2013">
    <Value Y="0"/>
```

Becomes this:

```
<TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jun&#xA;&#xD;2013">
    <Value/>
```

Does DataSet.ReadXml(MemoryStream) build the DataSet structure based off the first XML nodes it sees?
Is there a way to read in the XML structure prior to loading the dataset so the DataSet is not automatically created created from the first few nodes it finds?

Here are XML snippets showing the known good and known bad xml nodes and values.

Known Good:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="MyReport2 http://reportserver?%2FMyReport2&amp;rs

%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="MyReport2" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="MyReport2">
    <Rehosp30DaysCurrDxChart1>
        <Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_DxGroupName Label="Episode Of Care 

As Treatment DxGroupName">
            <TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Oct&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Nov&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Dec&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jan&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Feb&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Mar&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Apr&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="May&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jun&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jul&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Aug&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Sep&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
            </TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
        </Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_DxGroupName>
        <Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_Pneumonia Label="Episode Of 

Care As Treatment Pneumonia">
            <TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Oct&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Nov&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Dec&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jan&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Feb&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Mar&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Apr&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="1"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="May&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jun&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jul&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Aug&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Sep&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
            </TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
        </Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_Pneumonia>
    </Rehosp30DaysCurrDxChart1>
</Report>
```

Known Bad:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="MyReport2 http://reportserver?%2FMyReport2&amp;rs

%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="MyReport2" 

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="MyReport2">
    <Rehosp30DaysCurrDxChart1>
        <Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_DxGroupName Label="Episode Of Care 

As Treatment DxGroupName">
            <TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jul&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Aug&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Sep&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Oct&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Nov&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Dec&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jan&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Feb&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Mar&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Apr&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="May&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jun&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
            </TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
        </Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_DxGroupName>
        <Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_Pneumonia Label="Episode Of 

Care As Treatment Pneumonia">
            <TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jul&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Aug&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Sep&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Oct&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Nov&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Dec&#xA;&#xD;2012">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jan&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Feb&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Mar&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Apr&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="1"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="May&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
                <TrendingChartGroup2 Label="Jun&#xA;&#xD;2013">
                    <Value Y="0"/>
                </TrendingChartGroup2>
            </TrendingChartGroup2_Collection>
        </Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_Pneumonia>
    </Rehosp30DaysCurrDxChart1>
</Report>
```

Any help would be appreciated. I don't understand how DataSet.ReadXml(MemoryStream) builds the dataset.

Thanks!

Edit: I should add I need this in a dataset because the existing code uses datasets all over the place.  Is there a way to go XDocument to DataSet that fixes this problem?

Comment: I suspect the structure of the SSRS xml data is hierarchical and normal dataset in XML format is flattened structure. What are to trying to accomplish by reading the data? I assume you are transforming it for some other purpose? Why wouldn't you just skip the SSRS process and query the db directly?

Comment: We're doing automated testing of SSRS report output (xml) against 'known good' queries from the transactional database. The SSRS reports use MDX queries against cubed data. We're comparing the SSRS output to 'known good' queries. Both the QA queries and SSRS XML data goes into datatables for manipulation and comparison.  Normally the XML goes in great, just not when there is small amounts of data. :/

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't used DataSet.Readxml in this scenario at all. It might be a good idea to re-think the method of reading your xml. .NET provides a number of methods to do this. Here are some articles to review.

- http://support.softartisans.com/kbview.aspx?ID=674
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164116.aspx

You question then becomes, **how to unit test SSRS output**. Furthermore as a unit tester are you wanting to test the SSRS structure of the xml or the values provided within the structure?

**Testing the structure**

I loaded the SSRS xml into Visual Studio and used the XML menu to generate and xml schema ([XSD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29)) document. It obvious that the schema design includes meta data from the reports MDX query, so if you want to validate the xml structure generated is correct, you probably will need to create some template document and substitute some of the element names and then use some of the .net xml structure validation methods. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307379

```
<xs:element name="Rehosp30DaysCurrDxChart1">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Episode_x0020_Of_x0020_Care_x0020_From_x0020_Hospital_x0020_DxGroupName">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="TrendingChartGroup2_Collection">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TrendingChartGroup2">
                        <xs:complexType>
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Value" />
                          </xs:sequence>
                          <xs:attribute name="Label" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="Label" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
```

**Testing the data**

Text xml data in a unit test can be done a number of ways. You can walk the xml dom or use xPath to confirm values. This might make your unit tests a bit convoluted.

**Text the raw xml output**

Finally if you have a set of good xml results, you could just compare the raw xml text from SSRS to your "expected xml result" as a simple alternative to the two approaches above. While I have not used it, you might want to checkout any xml unit testing tools like http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/